# Form.Print() with DataGridView in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, printing, datagridview

I am printing invoices in my program by launching a form which I styled and which does automatically print itself onLoad by using Form.Print() method.

Now this is working great but I have placed a DataGridView inside that form which does contain the order description (items list) to be printed on the invoice. This is working now but the DataGridView has a specific height and if I have many items in my order I need the DataGridView (and the form) to automatically adjust its height to show all the items on the invoice.

I am not sure how to expand the DataGridView in height, and is it the right way to print an invoice in my program?

I don't want to use crystal reports because I am generating a QR Code at the bottom of the form so the cashier can scan it.

Comment: 1) The `System.Windows.Forms.Form` class do not have a `Print` method. 2) `GridView` is not the same as a `DataGridView`. 3) Are you willing to share some relevant code?

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå you are right it's a DataGridView. I just fixed that in the question above. And I have "Imports System.Drawing.Printing" maybe you need that for it to work. And the code for this is long and doesn't help for the purpose of this question. I only need a generic answer. Is it correct to print an invoice in VB.NET by printing the form or there is another approach? And in both cases, can we expand the height of the DataGridView automatically instead of having a static height? (Of course by counting the rows and assigning a height in pixel for each, but can that be done?)

Comment: It's impossible to answer your question as we don't know how you _"print the form"_. There are no extended `Form.Print` method in `System.Drawing.Printing`. So my only advice is that you look at the  [PrintDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Comment: He's using the PrintForm component.  Clearly it runs completely out of gas when the form has a grid that displays more rows than can fit the form.  That really does mean that he'll have to stop using PrintForm and start using PrintDocument, no two ways about it.  The QR scanner will work much better as well.

Comment: Thanks guys you are right it turned to be a component and its best to use PrintDocument instead. Can you please post that as a an aswer so I accept it, with a little sample code I can refer to in the future? The examples I found were for plain text, if you have an example with tables and images that will be perfect. Thanks again

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå I forgot to tag you in my comment above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I went with PrintDocument instead of PrintForm.

My only concern was that I wanted to layout the document to print with images and tables, and it turned out that the best way to do it, is to create a Word Document inside VB.NET and manipulate the data in it then print that document.

Thanks for people who commented on my question and helped me figure it out.